I can't run my flutter project when I try to integrate with firebase on MacBook with Xcode
I'm using Mac and I can't run my flutter project if try integrate with firebase.
I can run the first flutter project easily with the Xcode simulator(iPhone 15), but when configure the firebase to my project I can't run.
flutterfire configure log
The problem comes before a add firebase_core dependency
this is the error on debug console:
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 Pro Max in debug mode...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-RunnerTests`: (``)

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.28.0' defined in 'firebase_core'

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "firebase_core":
      In Podfile:
        firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`)

    Specs satisfying the `firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `tap'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:682:in `attempt_to_activate'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1082:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1080:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:125:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `12.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Error: The plugin "firebase_core" requires a higher minimum iOS deployment version than your application is targeting.
To build, increase your application's deployment target to at least 13.0 as described at https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.

Image error on console after debug
Flutter version: 3.22.2
firebase_core dependency version: firebase_core: ^3.2.0
I tried to uncomment a line of Podfile inside ios folder but it didn't work, I also tried to install the flutter, Xcode, android studio again but it didn't work too. Some people says that I should remove the podfile.lock and reinstall the pod using pod install but I didn't find the pod file.lock and I can't run the pod install
It that's happens when I try to run pod install
try to run pod install error image

Try this, open the terminal and from the ios folder of your project run the command: pod update Firebase/core
